# How to create a scatter plot where values are across multiple columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly-python

I have a dataframe in Pandas in which the rows are observations at different times and each column is a size bin where the values represent the number of particles observed for that size bin. So it looks like the following:

```
         bin1    bin2    bin3    bin4    bin5
Time1    50      200     30      40      5

Time2    60      60      40      420     700

Time3    34      200     30      67      43
```

I would like to use plotly/cufflinks to create a scatterplot in which the x axis will be each size bin, and the y axis will be the values in each size bin. There will be three colors, one for each observation.

As I'm more experienced in Matlab, I tried indexing the values using iloc (note the example below is just trying to plot one observation):

```
df.iplot(kind="scatter",theme="white",x=df.columns, y=df.iloc[1,:])
```

But I just get a key error: 0 message.

Is it possible to use indexing when choosing x and y values in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than indexing, I think you need to better understand how `pandas` and `matplotlib` interact each other.

Let's go by steps for your case:

1. As the [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) documentation says, the plotted series is a column. You have the series in the row, so you need to transpose your dataframe.
2. To create a scatterplot, you need both x and y coordinates in different columns, but you are missing the x column, so you also need to create a column with the x values in the transposed dataframe.
3. Apparently `pandas` does not change color by default with consecutive calls to `plot` (`matplotlib` does it), so you need to pick a color map and pass a color argument, otherwise all points will have the same color.

Here a working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Here I copied you data in a data.txt text file and import it in pandas as a csv.
#You may have a different way to get your data.
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\s+', engine='python')

#I assume to have a column named 'time' which is set as the index, as you show in your post.
df.set_index('time')

tdf = df.transpose() #transpose the dataframe

#Drop the time column from the trasponsed dataframe. time is not a data to be plotted.
tdf = tdf.drop('time')

#Creating x values, I go for 1 to 5 but they can be different.
tdf['xval'] = np.arange(1, len(tdf)+1)

#Choose a colormap and making a list of colors to be used.
colormap = plt.cm.rainbow
colors = [colormap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, len(tdf))]

#Make an empty plot, the columns will be added to the axes in the loop.
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
for i, cl in enumerate([datacol for datacol in tdf.columns if datacol != 'xval']):
    tdf.plot(x='xval', y=cl, kind="scatter", ax=axes, color=colors[i])

plt.show()
```

This plots the following image:

[image: plot example]

[Here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) a tutorial on picking colors in matplotlib.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realized shortly after taking a break from the problem that the heart of the solution would be in transposing the dataframe. Thanks again for the answer!